# How to place an element next to a grid in Foundation 6?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a grid with an image in a column of size `small-12` and I want to add next to it on the right side an element, for example a div. The column must be of size `small-12` so I can't set it to `small-11` and add the div next to it with a size of `small-1`. How can I do this? Is this related to CSS pseudo elements or classes maybe?

I tried to place it with CSS and `position: absolute;` but it is not where I want it - like there is a minimum margin to top and side for elements so `top: 0vh;` won't work.

See this CodePen snippet: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akwjgg
I'm not sure if using absolute position is good and also this breaks the responsiveness. Also the mail icon should be at top without margin-top as like as the small-12 column. So how to do it correctly?

Please reply with a way **without** using SASS because I'm using an online CDN where I can't control the variables.

Comment: foundation for sites, emails, or apps? Also, please provide a codepen of your initial efforts.

Comment: For sites - I will edit my post and add a codepen example. Give me some seconds.

Comment: I've added a snippet @MassDebates. I hope my intention is clear now!

Comment: So, the div you are adding to the right side must also be small-12? And, if so, you want them to be side by side in the small screen or medium or all?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the row's style (Or in your example's case, the div with the ID  '`#big_column`' to have `position:relative;` instead of `position:initial;` - This will allow elements within it to utilize its location and boxmodel properties for determining their own position if they're set to `position:absolute;`

see updated codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKJabd?editors=1100

relevant CSS:

```
#big_column {
  background-color: #ccc;

position:relative;  /* Position:absolute... */
      height:3em;   /* ... elements inside will use the...*/
  padding:1em;      /* ... lowest ascendant element set to Position:relative; */
}

#mail {
  display:inline-block;
  right:1%;
  bottom:-0.25em;
  position:absolute; /* Uses #big_column's box-model properties (like dimensions, location, etc. to define the appropriate/relevant properties of its own */
}
```